# Spinner and EditText - work around

Tags: android

I want to show EditText. On tapping edit text, Spinner should open. On selecting item in spinner, the value should be populated in edit text.

```
gender.setText(AppVars.Gender.Male.name)
```

gender is EditText and genderSpinner is Spinner

When I tap the gender edittext, it does open the spinner and on choosing the item, the chosen item sits in edit text. All good. But if I dont select anything in the spinner and click some where on screen, the spinner values are not shown instead only default value is shown at the bottom of the screen.

I want to get rid of this.

If I click anywhere else in the screen, the spinner should disappear. Is it possible?

Below is the code,

```
var genderInt: Int = AppVars.Gender.Male.genderVal

genderSpinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter<AppVars.Gender>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AppVars.Gender.values()))
gender.setText(AppVars.Gender.Male.name)
genderSpinner.setSelection(AppVars.Gender.Male.genderVal)

val genderListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        info("Nothing selected*********************")
        genderSpinner.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        val genderEnum: AppVars.Gender = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as AppVars.Gender
        info("Item selected*********************")
        genderInt = genderEnum.genderVal
        gender.setText(genderEnum.name)
        genderSpinner.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }

}

genderSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = genderListener

gender.setOnClickListener {
    genderSpinner.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    genderSpinner.performClick()
}
```

Comment: What library or framework are you using? looks like your code's a hybrid.

Comment: How many genders is your app supporting? If its only male and female, wouldn't a RadioButton make more sense?

Comment: I am using kotlin and anko

Comment: My company needs to display undefined as well. So I need spinner

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use `AutoCompleteTextView` to do all what you want easily instead of using `EditText` and `Spinner`. [Here you have a good tutoial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_autocompletetextview_control.htm) and 
also the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Sorry, I really need to use Spinner